# Update links on "how to ask" page from http to https

Tags: feature-request, help-center, ssl

The ["How to ask" page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) currently lists `http://sqlfiddle.com/` and `http://jsbin.com/` as recommended external sites to create live code examples:

> If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use Stack Snippets to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS.

I'd recommend updating these to the following because the existing links don't automatically redirect to `https`.

`http://sqlfiddle.com/` -> `https://www.db-fiddle.com/` (because sqlfiddle.com doesn't support HTTPS)

`http://jsbin.com/` -> `https://jsbin.com/`

---

Additionally, 3 links at the bottom of the page link to `http` websites too. but these automatically redirect to `https` so they're lower urgency to have updated.

```
Writing the perfect question
How do I ask and answer homework questions?
How to debug small programs
```

Comment: db-fiddle.com isn't a good choice of alternative fiddle for databases, in my opinion. Compared to some its choice of RDBMS is limited (just MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite). I can't access sqlfiddle.com (I get a time out error) to validate what options it has, but the site I use (dbfiddle.uk) has 9 choices of RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks for adding tags, I was having trouble finding relevant ones myself :). And that's fair, https://dbfiddle.uk/ would be an improvement too for the number of RDBMS choices. Though its UI is less user-friendly to sqlfiddle/db-fiddle, especially for users who may be new to SQL. Maybe this page could link to both?

Comment: @Larnu the big advantage of db-fiddle.com though is the text to DDL feature. Great for all those questions with ASCII tables of data instead of DDL/DML statements.